# Calculating unit vector

Tags: linear-algebra

[The vector in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1UyV.png)

Hello,

I was wondering how do I calculate the unit vector when it is given in the parametric form. I know that the formula for a unit vector is V/magnitude of V.

Answer (score 0):

You have right, the unit vector is given by $$\frac{[x_1,7x_1]}{\sqrt{x_1^2
+49x_1^2}}$$